# SQL Query to return different row data into a single line

Tags: sql

I have some transactional ledger data which I would like to parse as a single line. A single line has the transaction account code, account name, invoice number etc, and another line has the payment date. I would like to combine into 1 and discard the rest.

Refer to image below

Thank you very much in advance of your assistance.

Many thanks,

Jamie

```
SELECT 
tblTranHeader.lOriginatingTransactionID,
tblTranHeader.lTransactionID,
OwnersCorporation .sPlanNumber,
Account.sAccountNumber,
tblTranHeader.dTranDate,
EOMONTH(tblTranHeader.dTranDate) as MonthYY ,
Account.sName,
tblTranHeader.sDescription,
tblTranHeader.sRefNumber,
tblTranEntry.mAmount*-1
FROM tblTranHeader
INNER JOIN tblTranEntry on tblTranEntry.lTransactionID = tblTranHeader.lTransactionID
INNER JOIN OwnersCorporation on OwnersCorporation.lOwnersCorporationID = tblTranHeader.lOwnersCorporationID
INNER JOIN Account on  Account.lAccountID = tblTranEntry.lAccountID
Where OwnersCorporation.lOwnersCorporationID not in (92,20, 3)
 and Account.lAccountID not in (340,341,342,343,344,345,377)
 and sPlanNumber like '%72640%' 
 and mAmount = '4369.38' or mAmount = '-4369.38'

 order by 2
```

EDIT - Added mage of Desired Output

[IMAGE Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA6jc.png)

[IMAGE Keep Yellow as a single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uv3E.png)

Comment: If you can please give us a expect output. like what will the data looks like instead of a picture with some yellow highlight.

Comment: @T.Peter, THanks, I have added an image to the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining source query to aggregate of that query that calculates `MAX` of those dated fields. Below uses related CTEs that are joined together in final query and table aliases are used to avoid re-writing long identifiers.

```sql
WITH sub AS (
    SELECT 
         h.lOriginatingTransactionID
         , h.lTransactionID
         , o.sPlanNumber
         , a.sAccountNumber
         , h.dTranDate
         , EOMONTH(h.dTranDate) AS MonthYY
         , a.sName
         , h.sDescription
         , h.sRefNumber
         , e.mAmount*-1  AS mAmount                               -- ADDED NAMED ALIAS
    FROM tblTranHeader h
    INNER JOIN tblTranEntry e
       ON e.lTransactionID = h.lTransactionID
    INNER JOIN OwnersCorporation o
       ON o.lOwnersCorporationID = h.lOwnersCorporationID
    INNER JOIN Account a
       ON a.lAccountID = e.lAccountID
    WHERE o.lOwnersCorporationID NOT IN (92,20, 3)
      AND a.lAccountID NOT IN (340,341,342,343,344,345,377)
      AND o.sPlanNumber LIKE '%72640%' 
      AND (e.mAmount = '4369.38' OR e.mAmount = '-4369.38')       -- PARENTHESES ADDED DUE TO OR LOGIC
), agg AS (
   SELECT lOriginatingTransactionID
           , MAX(dTranDate) AS dTranDate
           , MAX(MonthYY) AS MonthYY
   FROM sub
   GROUP BY lOriginatingTransactionID
)

SELECT sub.sAccount
        , agg.dTranDate
        , agg.MonthYY
        , sub.SName
        , sub.sDescription
        , sub.sRefNumber
        , sub.mAmount 
FROM sub
INNER JOIN agg
   ON sub.lOriginatingTransactionID = agg.lOriginatingTransactionID
  AND sub.sAccount = 159100
```

Comment: Wonderful, works perfectly. Thanks for your help guru!